# jQuery sortable update a hidden field with image ID's after sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, input, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following html:

```
<section class="layers-multi-image-container layers-has-multi-image">

<ul class="layers-multi-image-list multi-image-list layers-sortable ui-sortable">
<!-- Image -->

<li>
  <span class="layers-multi-image-remove"></span>
  <img id="3942" class="multi-image-reveal" src="http://www.samskirrow.com/skizzar-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/10421285_704957996239240_3163365373846263623_n-150x150.jpg" height="100" width="100">
</li>

<li>
  <span class="layers-multi-image-remove"></span>
  <img id="3941" class="multi-image-reveal" src="http://www.samskirrow.com/skizzar-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/10410229_625721974162843_807090703954128681_n-150x150.jpg" height="100" width="100">
</li>

<li>
  <span class="layers-multi-image-remove"></span>
  <img id="3940" class="multi-image-reveal" src="http://www.samskirrow.com/skizzar-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/10393797_700706529997720_5352493934534579125_n-150x150.jpg" height="100" width="100">
</li>

<li>
  <span class="layers-multi-image-remove"></span>
  <img id="3939" class="multi-image-reveal" src="http://www.samskirrow.com/skizzar-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1375655_695160727218967_999194590829985843_n-150x150.jpg" height="100" width="100">
</li>

<li>
  <span class="layers-multi-image-remove"></span>
  <img id="3938" class="multi-image-reveal" src="http://www.samskirrow.com/skizzar-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/995923_479016332166742_287465340_n-150x150.jpg" height="100" width="100">
</li>

<li>
  <span class="layers-multi-image-remove"></span>
  <img id="3937" class="multi-image-reveal" src="http://www.samskirrow.com/skizzar-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/941640_453041514764224_1669353328_n-150x150.jpg" height="100" width="100">
</li>

<li>
  <span class="layers-multi-image-remove"></span>
  <img id="3947" class="multi-image-reveal" src="http://www.samskirrow.com/skizzar-test/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/10489808_625721990829508_5517316366768913809_n-150x150.jpg" height="100" width="100">
</li>

</ul>

  <input type="text" class="image_ids" id="widget-layers-widget-gallery-33-images" name="widget-layers-widget-gallery[33][images]" value="3942,3941,3940,3939,3938,3937,3947">
</section>
```

The images in the above example are dynamically inserted by the user, i.e. there could be more or less, and they will all have unique ID's.

I am using jQuery sortable to allow my users to change the order, as follows:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("ul.layers-multi-image-list").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var ordering = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
      $('.image_ids').val(ordering);
   }
});

   $('ul.layers-multi-image-list').disableSelection();
});
```

When the user changes the order of the images, I would like the new order of image IDs to be updated in the text input.

At the minute, when the user changes the order, my code returns the following ,,,,,,,,,

Here is a jsfiddle showing my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/5afo47k1/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` at `update` function returns parent `ul` element .

Try substituting selector `$("> li img", this)` for `this` at `update` callback ; using `$.map()` , `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `","`

```
  var ordering = $.map($("> li img", this), function(el) {return el.id}).join(",");
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5afo47k1/5/